# load configuration data at runtime

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables, environment

I saw a lot of articles about loading configuration fields at runtime, but nothing solve the problem when you have multiple environments/domains in this file, lets say google, stackoverflow, etc as presented below.

```
{
  "localhost": {
    "api": "http://localhost:42324",
    "production": false
  },
  "google": {
    "api": "https://google.com",
    "production": true
  },
  "stackoverflow": {
    "api": "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "production": true
  }
}
```

Using a config service and `APP_INITIALIZER` (from angular), I load the configuration file and inject the fields in my application. I see there are 2 ways to do that, one adding all these specified above in the `providers` array, and the second to use `ngDoBootstrap`, which will wait for configuration to be loaded before bootstraping the application.

```
providers: [
  {
     provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
     useFactory: appInitializerFn,
     multi: true,
     deps: [ConfigService]
  }
]


export class AppModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
    this.configService.init().then(() => app.bootstrap(AppComponent));
  }
}
```

**The problem:**

How I filter the configuration object, to load only what I need from there. for domain `google.com` to load only object `google`, for domain `stackoverflow.com` to load only object `stackoverflow`.

Maybe a solution:
I'm thinking to use `window.location` to get the domain. Using that way, I can filter the json and get only the specific configuration object. And my service `init` method will be:

```
init(): Promise<AppConfig | undefined> {
   return this.http
      .get<any | undefined>('./app-config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then((config) => {
        const host = window.location.host;

        if (typeof config !== 'undefined') {
          switch (host) {
            case 'http://localhost:4200': {
              this.configuration = config.localhost;
              break;
            }
            case 'https://google.com': {
              this.configuration = config.google;
              break;
            }
            case 'https://stackoverflow.com': {
              this.configuration = config.stackoverflow;
              break;
            }
            default:
              this.configuration = { ... };
          }
        }

        return this.configuration;
   });
}
```

I tested it with different localhost ports and using `window.location.port`, but not yet in production. I'm thinking if this solution is ok, or should exists another way to do that.

I'm imagined that I can give some parameters when execute a command to run angular application, but this is outside the environment, because the angular app is just a `/dist` folder with all the files, and an external process (`nginx/nodejs` service) will listen to that folder to run the application.

// another idea was that the `app-config.json` file to contains fields with variables which will be populated somehow ...

```
{
  "api": "${API_URL}",
  "production": "${PRODUCTION_MODE}"
}
```

summary: Is something like "build once for all environments"

Comment: *'m imagined that I can give some parameters when execute a command to run angular application* nope, as you are not running the app but rather client's browser does.

Comment: When do you know which configuration you are going will require in your application? Only at runtime?

Comment: yes, only at runtime. the idea is to have only one build for multiple domains. So, I need to identify which is the domain, or to read something from the server to be able to get the right configuration file. I can't see another way. I'm not sure if the request is too strange and if I can find a solution for that. It is wanted that the app to be builded only once and deployed on multiple different domains (not something like multiple instances, there are different applications with different configuration, but with the same core code)

Comment: Then this is the way to go

Comment: What about having only one config object and after deployment, to rewrite it from a local service written in `express.js`? :d this should be another option. But the disadvantage should be that this service should be installed on all machines and run from a pipeline after app deployment.

Comment: You have just moved the problem from angular app, to application serving the "right" config fille. This is the reason why I have asked when will you know. Is it on runtime, deployment or compile time as those can be handled differently.